# Your request cannot be processed at this time. Please try again later. If this message persists, please contact GSX support via the help function

Tags: php

While ordering apple gsx **Apple Protection Plan** i'm getting an error like this.

> GSX.SYS.002
>   Your request cannot be processed at this time. Please try again later. If this message persists, please contact GSX support via the help function.null

Can anyone were I did mistake or how to order app using gsx in php?

But the same way I tried to get apple warranty details it's working fine,
and it show an error like

```
$CreateAPPOrder  =   array (
    'CreateAPPOrderRequest' => array 
    (
        'userSession' => array ('userSessionId' => $sessionid) ,
        'orderData' => array 
        (
            'addressLine1' =>$mcpadress1,
            'addressLine2' =>$mcpadress2,
            'city' =>$mcpcity,
            'companyName' =>'',
            'country' =>$mccountry,
            'emailAddress' =>$mccmail,
            'firstName' =>$mcpfname,
            'lastName' =>$mcplname,
            'primaryPhone' =>$mcpmobile,                                            
            'productNumber' =>$mcprdno,
            'purchaseOrder' =>$mcporder,
            'requestPart' =>array('displaySerialNumber'=>$mcserno1,'serialNumber'=>$mcserno1,'fileName'=>'','fileData'=>'') ,
            'shipTo' =>$mnshipto,
            'county' =>'',
            'state' =>$mcpstate,
            'zipCode' =>$mcpncode,
            'pocDeliveryPreference' =>'',
            'pocLanguage' =>'',
            'purchaseMode' =>$mcpmode

         )
     )
    );
    $response1  =   $client->CreateAPPOrder($CreateAPPOrder) ;       
    $response1  =   object_to_array($response1) ;   
    //var_dump($response1);        
    // inserting the response in to apb table        
    $operationId             =   $response1['CreateAPPOrderResponse']['operationId']                                ;
    $agreeNo                 =   $response1['CreateAPPOrderResponse']['orderConfirmation']['agreementNumber']                    ;
    $ttforder                =   $response1['orderConfirmation']['totalFromOrder']                     ;
    $partNumber              =   $response1['orderConfirmation']['orderParts']['partNumber']            ;
    $netPrice                =   $response1['orderConfirmation']['orderParts']['netPrice']            ;
    $currency                =   $response1['orderConfirmation']['orderParts']['currency']            ;
    $quantity                =   $response1['orderConfirmation']['orderParts']['quantity']            ;
    $vattax                  =   $response1['orderConfirmation']['tax']                                  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is because Apple server temp down it seems . so just try after some time.